# django model forms encoding

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with using utf-8 characters in Model Forms in django. I have this code in model :

```
class Student (models.Model):
    imie = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Imię', max_length=40)
    nazwisko = models.CharField(max_length=40)

(...)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s'(self.imie, self.nazwisko)
```

When i try to save this in a editor and run runserver command, the server sends Validating models... message and hangs, wihtout any error, and i can't refresh the page cause server can't start. When i insert normal (non unicode) in verbose_name='Imie' everything works great. What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set file encoding to UTF-8 by writing the following at the top of the file.

```
# coding=utf8
```

Then add a lower case u before the string.

```
verbose_name=u'Imię'
```

More info about encodings in Python in [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use a `unicode`.

```
    imie = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Imię', max_length=40)
```

Comment: forgot to mention that i used u'' and even after restarts it stills Validating models... and do nothing. No error message is really a problem